# Use specific column to lookup a value based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, sql-update

I have the following situation in a database I am designing...

```
**Value Table**
+-------+------------+-----------+------------+---------+-------+--------+
| id    |   use_col  | col_1     | col_2      | col_3   | … etc | Lookup |
+-------+------------+-----------+------------+---------+-------+--------+
| 1     | col_1      | 0.5       | no         | low     | …     | ?      |
| 2     | col_2      | 0.1       | yes        | low     | …     | ?      |
| 3     | col_3      | 0.2       | no         | high    | …     | ?      |
| … etc | …          | …         | …          | …       | …     | …      |
+-------+------------+-----------+------------+---------+-------+--------+

**Lookup Table**
+------------+-------------+--------+
|   use_col  | Value Range | Lookup |
+------------+-------------+--------+
| col_1      | 0.1         | 5      |
| col_1      | 0.2         | 4      |
| col_1      | 0.3         | 3      |
| col_1      | 0.4         | 2      |
| col_1      | 0.5         | 1      |
| col_2      | no          | 5      |
| col_2      | yes         | 1      |
| col_3      | low         | 4      |
| col_3      | medium      | 3      |
| col_3      | high        | 2      |
| col_3      | very high   | 1      |
| … etc      | …           | …      |
+------------+-------------+--------+
```

And I need to use the value in the field associated to the [use_col] field to return the matching [Lookup] in the [Lookup Table] and write that value to the [Value Table]. i.e. I my final table needs to have the following  information in it.

```
+-------+------------+-----------+------------+---------+-------+--------+
| id    |   use_col  | col_1     | col_2      | col_3   | … etc | Lookup |
+-------+------------+-----------+------------+---------+-------+--------+
| 1     | col_1      | 0.5       | no         | low     | …     | 1      |
| 2     | col_2      | 0.1       | yes        | low     | …     | 1      |
| 3     | col_3      | 0.2       | no         | high    | …     | 2      |
| … etc | …          | …         | …          | …       | …     | …      |
+-------+------------+-----------+------------+---------+-------+--------+
```

How can I go about writing a SQL UPDATE query to do this? Keeping in mind that it needs to work regardless of the amount of [use_col] values in the data structure.

Comment: Is it an update or an insert you need?

Comment: Which database are you using?  Every database has slightly different update syntax. Also, are the number of columns to match known or are they variable?

Comment: @Tim I am using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `join` to construct the table:

```
select vt.*, l.lookup
from valuetable vt left join
     lookup l
     on vt.use_col = l.use_col and
        ( (vt.user_col = 'col1' and vt.col1 = l.value) or
          (vt.user_col = 'col2' and vt.col2 = l.value) or
          (vt.user_col = 'col3' and vt.col3 = l.value) 
        )
```

In your example, all the lookup values are different, so perhaps you can simplify this to:

```
select vt.*, l.lookup
from valuetable vt left join
     lookup l
     on vt.use_col = l.use_col and
        l.value in ( vt.col1, vt.col2, vt.col3 );
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Oops.  I thought the question was tagged Oracle.  I changed the code to be more generic.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using an update join:

```
UPDATE Value v
INNER JOIN Lookup l1
    ON v.col_1 = l1.value_range AND l1.use_col = 'col_1'
INNER JOIN Lookup l2
    ON v.col_2 = l2.value_range AND l2.use_col = 'col_2'
INNER JOIN Lookup l3
    ON v.col_3 = l3.value_range AND l3.use_col = 'col_3'
SET v.Lookup = COALESCE(l1.Lookup, l2.Lookup, l3.Lookup);
```

The `COALESCE` expression above will take the first non `NULL` lookup value it encounters.  Your sample data imply that only a single lookup value would be non `NULL`, so the order should not matter there.

We *could* try to do this with a single join, but join conditions with very complex logic can be real performance killers.

Comment: is there someway a query can be created without having to "hard code" a new inner join every time a new use_col is added? Also there is the possibility that col_1, col_2 and col_3 all have data for the same row. I have updated the question to suit.

Comment: To your first question, no, you can't do that without dynamic SQL.  To the second part, if the value table can have more than one non NULL value then your question doesn't even make sense, because you have not given us any logic for _which_ lookup value to use.

Comment: hmmm ok fair enough. Guess i'll just have to hard code it in then. The use_col field tells you which lookup column and therefore value to use.

Comment: But the bigger question is do you ever expect multiple _matches_ for each row?  If not, then my query is salvagable because `COALESCE` will still fish out the non NULL single matching value.

Comment: No only ever expect one match for each row

Answer (score 0):

This is a select that will produce the result you search for.

```
select a.use_col, a.col_1, a.col_2, a.col_3, b.look_up
from value_table a, look_up_table b
where a.use_col = b.use_col
and a.use_col = 'col_1'
and a.col_1 = b.value_range
union
select a.use_col, a.col_1, a.col_2, a.col_3, b.look_up
from value_table a, look_up_table b
where a.use_col = b.use_col
and a.use_col = 'col_2'
and a.col_2 = b.value_range
union
select a.use_col, a.col_1, a.col_2, a.col_3, b.look_up
from value_table a, look_up_table b
where a.use_col = b.use_col
and a.use_col = 'col_3'
and a.col_3 = b.value_range
union
...
```

You can use it in a view, or insert it into a new table with:

```
inset into result_table select (put here the query)
```